# Can't use DataRow object for DataGridView current row, but can using the same code for another DGV

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datarow, datagridviewrow

In a C# WinForms project I have two DGVs with similar functionality, just different data.

For each, when the user changes the value of editable cells I'm using `CellValueChanged` to Change the color of the cell if what the user typed is different than the value that was in the cell.

Here's the code for that. Everything works as needed & intended.

```
private void dgvXref_CellValueChanged(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int intRowIndex = dgvXref.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int intColIndex = dgvXref.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

    DataRow drCurrRow = dtXref.Rows[intRowIndex];
    string strOriginalValue = drCurrRow[intColIndex, DataRowVersion.Original].ToString();
    string strEnteredValue = drCurrRow[intColIndex, DataRowVersion.Proposed].ToString();

    if (strOriginalValue != strEnteredValue)
    {
        dgvXref.Rows[intRowIndex].Cells[intColIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else
    {
        dgvXref.Rows[intRowIndex].Cells[intColIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Empty;
    }
}
```

I need to do the same thing for the other DGV as well, so I just copy/pasted the code and changed the DGV's name:

```
private void dgvDefaults_CellValueChanged(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int intRowIndex = dgvDefaults.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int intColIndex = dgvDefaults.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

    DataRow drCurrRow = dgvDefaults.Rows[intRowIndex];
    string strOriginalValue = drCurrRow[intColIndex, DataRowVersion.Original].ToString();
    string strEnteredValue = drCurrRow[intColIndex, DataRowVersion.Proposed].ToString();

    if (strOriginalValue != strEnteredValue)
    {
        dgvDefaults.Rows[intRowIndex].Cells[intColIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else
    {
        dgvDefaults.Rows[intRowIndex].Cells[intColIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Empty;
    }
}
```

My problem is, for the second DGV, `dgvDefaults.Rows[intRowIndex]` has a red error line under it, saying, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' so 'System.Data.DataRow'. Which totally confuses me, since I'm doing the same thing on the other DGV, but there's no error and it runs fine. The DataSets for each of the DGVs is set up the same and the DGVs' properties are the same - the only difference is the data they hold.

I tried changing the second DGV's `drCurrRow` code to `DataGridViewRow drCurrRow = dgvDefaults.Rows[intRowIndex];` and that doesn't have an error on it, but I can't figure out how to get the Original and Proposed version using that.

A) Why am I getting an error on that line for the second DGV but not the first
and
B) How can I accomplish my need for this?

Comment: Clean the solution, rebuild, restart.

Comment: @Crowcoder - no dice: the error didn't go away.

Comment: Does the project still build and run?

Comment: In both code blocks you can get the current bound `DataRow` like: `var drCurrRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRow;`. Also, I think you should handle the `CellFormatting` event instead.

Comment: @JQSOFT - I said it worked, but I'm editing this - ran it and drCurrRow is null on the line after that.

Comment: In short, handle the UI-Related events to control the presentation, and handle the Data-Related events to control the data.

Comment: You are trying to cast a DataGridViewRow to a DataRow. Seems you have naming typo. Check your objects names and types. Check this: `dtDefaults.GetType().Name;`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was a simple typo:

If you look closely at the line assigning the variable `drCurrRow`, in the first code block - the code for the working DGV - I have `DataRow drCurrRow = dtXref.Rows[intRowIndex];`, but in the second code block, for the second DGV I have `DataRow drCurrRow = dgvDefaults.Rows[intRowIndex];`. `DataRow` is a row in a `DataTable`, a `DataGridViewRow` is a row in a `DataGridView`. So JQSOFT's last comment was correct - I was casting a DataGridViewRow as a DataRow, due to a two-letter typo.